# Traversing complete binary tree to find min leaf sum

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to find the minimum path sum from the root node to any of the leaf node in a `complete` binary tree. I have the tree's level order traversal in an array. I have come up with the following recursion:

```
ans = tree[i] + min(rec_fn(2i+1), rec_fn(2i+2))
```

I have computed the time complexity of this recursive solution to be O(n) but I am not sure whether it is correct. Since I am traversering all the nodes once, I think the complexity should be O(n).

Also, if I store the results of the recursion in an array and use dynamic programming, will it help with the time complexity? will it bring the complexity down further?

Comment: You can't beat O(n) as you need to evaluate every node.  Any node can contain a value (negative infinity) that makes that particular path the optimal.

Comment: @ChristianSloper what if I had only positive values. In that case, I need not travel all the nodes

Comment: can't see how you can beat O(n), regardless, you need some sort of information that guarantees that a path you havent visited yet can't be better than what you have seen so far.  Since this is only a complete binary tree, i can't see what exra information you can have.

Comment: @ChristianSloper ah I see, but does that recursion really have a complexity of O(n) or is it O(n2), if its O(n2) storing the results in an array can bring down it to O(n)

Comment: calling it from the top it will reach every node once.  It is O(n).